# Bash path tab-complete for python -m

Tags: python, bash

When you run a script, you usually do so as follows:

`$ python path/to/script.py`

However, when running a [module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m), you run it as:

`$ python -m path.to.module`

It can sometimes be annoying to run a module from the command line because the `.` separators keep bash from being able to do tab-completion. Is there a custom tab-completion script out there that could handle this situation?

Comment: It would not be straightforward to write code to do this completion as one would think. Python has no built-in mechanism to "*detect everything that is importable*" and some modules can even be created dynamically on import!
What if some package uses a custom `find_module` function or even a custom `sys.meta_path`? The python import system is pluggable... One could make a package that generates a module on the fly for any name you import, then, all module names become valid!

Comment: I’ve seen a hacky solution that just turns the dots into slashes, guesses at the `sys.path`, and searches for .py, .pyc, and .so files, but that of course does the wrong thing in many cases (even basics like not finding things in zip and egg archives, getting 2.x Tkinter wrong, etc., in addition to the more complicated cases that nosklo mentioned).

Comment: It looks like [`argcomplete` added some kind of support for this](https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete/pull/204). I think `argcomplete` is trying to complete the arguments to your `-m module`, not the `-m` itself, but it might still have relevant code you can steal.